# How to get PostgreSQL to calculate the time between the current row and a previous row with another field meeting a certain value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like the following

| descript | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| START | 1/1/2024 08:00:00 |
| ACTIVITY1 | 1/1/2024 09:34:00 |
| ACTIVITY2 | 1/1/2024 11:12:00 |
| STOP | 1/1/2024 13:00:00 |

I need a query that will return the description, timestamp, and the duration between the start and stop time. Ideally, the output would have all records in the table but only populate the duration column when DESCRIPT contains STOP. The issue I'm facing is that the number of ACTIVITIES between the START and STOP times varies so I can't use a generalized LAG statement.

So, my desired output from the above table would look like this:

| descript | timestamp | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| START | 1/1/2024 08:00:00 |  |
| ACTIVITY1 | 1/1/2024 09:34:00 |  |
| ACTIVITY2 | 1/1/2024 11:12:00 |  |
| STOP | 1/1/2024 13:00:00 | 05:00:00 |

I was able to get close to what I want by creating a temp table that contained only the START and STOP records. My query looked like this:

```
SELECT descript, timestamp, 
CASE WHEN descript ilike 'START' THEN
(timestamp - LAG(timestamp) over (order by timestamp)) END as "duration"
from table
```

and the results looked like:

| descript | timestamp | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| START | 1/1/2024 08:00:00 |  |
| STOP | 1/1/2024 13:00:00 | 05:00:00 |

It works but I really want a query that will do this while maintaining the ACTIVITY records in between each START and STOP.

I am pretty new to SQL in general, so I'm sure this is possible with some sort of function but not sure the best way to go about it. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Not seeing where this *...but only populate the duration column when DESCRIPT contains OUT.* comes into play?

Comment: Union your final query with your first query. filter out the start/stop in the first query. Order by timestamp

Comment: @AdrianKlaver typo on my end, should say STOP not OUT. I edited and fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union your final query with your first query. filter out the start/stop in the first query. Order by timestamp

```
CREATE TABLE ACTIVITIES 
(
    descript    VARCHAR(512),
    timestamp   timestamp 
);

INSERT INTO ACTIVITIES (descript, timestamp) VALUES
    ('START', '1/1/2024 08:00:00'),
    ('ACTIVITY1', '1/1/2024 09:34:00'),
    ('ACTIVITY2', '1/1/2024 11:12:00'),
    ('STOP', '1/1/2024 13:00:00');

SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT *, NULL as "duration" 
  FROM ACTIVITIES 
  WHERE descript NOT in ('START','STOP')

  UNION ALL    

  SELECT descript, timestamp, 
  CASE WHEN descript ilike 'STOP' THEN
  (timestamp - LAG(timestamp) over (order by timestamp)) END as "duration"
  FROM ACTIVITIES
  WHERE descript in ('START','STOP')
) 
ORDER BY timestamp
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tzDuqnWA)

| descript | timestamp | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| START | 2024-01-01 08:00:00 | null |
| ACTIVITY1 | 2024-01-010 9:34:00 | null |
| ACTIVITY2 | 2024-01-01 11:12:00 | null |
| STOP | 2024-01-01 13:00:00 | 05:00:00 |

Comment: Also works with an example with multiple Start/Stops https://dbfiddle.uk/xbx95t2N